# How to analyze a categorical data based on a numerical data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a DataFrame which holds a numerical continuous column: "loan_amount" and a categorical column "loan_status" which holds values: `current`, `paid`, `default`. I wanted to analyze what is the effect of loan_amount on loan_status.

My first intuition is to create a column which holds intervals of loan_amount, that is to categorize it and then see its effect on loan_status.

I started with categorizing in the four quartiles and then I anm analyzing the effect of the categories on the loan_status using a pivot_table.

```
loan_df['loan_amnt_cat'] = pd.cut(loan_df['loan_amnt'], bins=[0, 500, 5500, 15000, 35000], labels=['upto 500', '501To5500', '5501To15000', 'more than 15001'])

loan_df.pivot_table(values='id', index='loan_status', aggfunc='count', columns='loan_amnt_cat')
```

The problem with the above approach is, the categories are still very broad, kindly suggest me a proper way to analyze this. I also want to analyze this through a plot but unable to come up with an idea. I am starting to learn data analysis and have very less knowledge in this field.

Comment: Not sure if this is the way to analyze this data. For example you can get some basic statistics per category (mean, median, std, range). So I think loan_status is the independent variable and not the other way around like you are suggesting.

Comment: @Erfan It could be independent but I can't analyze that manually, I want to check if there is any pattern. And yes, I am getting the `count()` stat in the pivot table.

Comment: Try: `loan_df.groupby('loan_amnt_cat').agg({'loan_amnt':['mean', 'median', 'first', 'last']})`

Comment: Or you can one hot encode your categorical data and try to find regression between the categorys and the loan. But for that we would need some example data to reproduce.

Comment: @Erfan I don't think I want this (`loan_df.groupby('loan_amnt_cat').agg....`). I want a count of  grouped values of `loan_status` so that I get to know a pattern of `loan_status` around an interval of `loan_amnt` And I am getting that but my range of analysis is quite big, I think I need proper intervals in the 25th and 75th quartile.

Comment: @Erfan I may have to read about your second comment. I quite new to data analysis. Terms like `hot encode` and `regression` are new to me.